# Python given number exists in list or not

Tags: python

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(a)
s=input("Enter a number from the list given \n")
if s in a:
    print("the number given is", s)
else:
    print("please select the number given in the list")
```

When I give 2 as input, the if statement is not being checked directly; the else part is printed. But if provide the value hardcoded in the program, the code is working as expected.

If my input is any number from the list, it should print that number. If not, the other part should be printed.

Answer (score 3):

```
s=int(input("Enter a number from the list given \n"))
```

I believe

Answer (score 0):

You are taking **string** as an input and not **int**. Try using
`s = int(input("Some value")`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your *if* condition like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(a)
s = input("Enter a number from the list given: ")
if s in set(str(e) for e in a):
    print("the number given is", s)
else:
    print("please select the number given in the list")
```

In this way you do not have to convert the user input to int which is fraught with problems if the value(s) entered cannot be converted to int.

An alternative is to use exception handling as follows:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

while True:
    try:
        print(a)
        s = int(input("Enter a number from the list given: "))
        if s in a:
            print("the number given is", s)
            break
        else:
            raise ValueError("please select the number given in the list")
    except ValueError as ve:
        print(ve)
```

Comment: If the main concern is the input casting to an int, you could better adjust the if statement to test for int(s) in a. That is much more efficient than casting the whole list to strings.

Comment: @Lexpj Agreed that it's less efficient. However, OP clearly has very limited knowledge of Python. The right way to do this is to convert user input to int within a loop that checks for ValueError exceptions. Given that OP knows very little about Python I though it inappropriate to introduce exception handling